# Java Servlet write to outputstream

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream, printwriter

I have a servlet that calls micro services. Micro Service instances return JSON objects as responses and I write those responses to HttpServletResponse response object's outputStream via this call :

`response.getWriter().write(serviceResponse.toString());`

For a reason I want to do something like this :

`new PrintWriter(response.getOutputStream()).write(serviceResponse.toString());`

but the below code does not write anything to the output. Servlet output is empty.

Is there any idea about how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried calling flush() on the PrintWriter?

Comment: Probably need to flush.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. calling flush() solved the issue.